# PSQL & Python = how to have returned a list of "elements"

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, python-2.7, psql

i have this code:

```
cur.execute("SELECT numbers FROM table")
supp = cur.fetchall()
for item in supp:
    print item
```

and it prints:

```
('one',)
('two',)
('three',)
```

how can i have?

```
one
two
three
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
    supp = cur.fetchall()
    for item in supp:
        print ' | '.join(item)
    return "values printed"
except:
    return "Something went wrong!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Each `item` correspond to a row of a result of your query, each row is represented by a *tuple*. If you want to get the first items of every tuple, you can [unpack them in the `for` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867882/tuple-unpacking-in-for-loops):

```
for value, in supp:
    print(value)
```

Or, you can just get the first items *by index* as well:

```
for row in supp:
    print(row[0])
```

You can also put them into a list with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
values = [value for value, in supp]
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> supp = [('one',), ('two', ), ('three', )]
>>> for value, in supp:
...     print(value)
... 
one
two
three
>>> [value for value, in supp]
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Comment: You can also used [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)s to get more readable results from SQL queries.  There's more information on using them [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20096972/6469907) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16336132/6469907).

Comment: it's not a normal list... your example doesn't work as you think .-.

Comment: @AldinSelimbasic well, let's start with what "does not work" for you? Any symptoms, errors?

Comment: it returns elements as "('one',)" instead of "one" as i need

Comment: @AldinSelimbasic sorry, may be there is some misunderstanding. Have you actually tried what I've posted? Thanks.

Comment: dude, i have a PostgreSQL named "table", one of the columns is "numbers".
By using a cursor i "capture" all values on the column numbers and put them inside a list.

on my DB i have [ one, two, three ] as varchars but my list made of the "captured" elements isn't made by strings [ one, two, three ] but strings [ ('one',),('two',),('three',) ]

i am looking for the method to have the well formatted strings returned

Comment: btw, thnx for loosing time for me :/

Comment: This answer is an exact fit for you question. If you can't read it then @alecxe really squandered his time.